# When using JSON Schema for validation, it is not recursively validate child entities?

Tags: jsonschema

When using the following schema

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
    "definitions":{
        "entity": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "parent": {"type": ["null","string"]},
                "exclude": {"type": "boolean"},
                "count": {"type": ["null","integer"]},
                "EntityType": {"type": "string"},
                "Children": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {"$ref":"#/definitions/entity"}
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "required": ["parent","EntityType","count"]
}
```

On this provided body of JSON

```
{
    "parent": "null",
    "EntityType": "test",
    "count": "null",
    "Children": [
        {
            "EntityType": "test",
            "count": 3
        },
        {
            "EntityType": "test"
        }
    ],
    "Extra": "somevalue"
}
```

It should be returning that I have provided an invalid Json object, however it does not seem to be doing so.

That said, if I were to have the root node not succeed (by removing one of the required fields) the validation works and says that I haven't provided a required field. Is there a reason that I am not able to validate the json recursively?

Comment: I think you could do the trick with https://www.npmjs.com/package/great-json-validator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want `parent`, `EntityType`, and `count` to be required properties of the `entity` definition.  However they're only required at the root, not the `entity` level.  I would suggest that you move the `required` keyword into the `entity` definition, then reference the definition as part of an `allOf` to ensure the root is compliant.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
    "definitions":{
        "entity": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "parent": {"type": ["null","string"]},
                "exclude": {"type": "boolean"},
                "count": {"type": ["null","integer"]},
                "EntityType": {"type": "string"},
                "Children": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {"$ref":"#/definitions/entity"}
                }
            },
            "required": ["parent","EntityType","count"]
        }
    },
    "allOf": [{"$ref": "#/definitions/entity"}]
}
```

Comment: Assuming this is draft-7, in the next version of JSON Schema (draft-8), you won't need to wrap the $ref in an `allOf`, although currently you do.

Comment: Great this solution did exactly what I need. Thank you for clarifying how I could use AllOf to validate recursively!

Comment: @relequestual a solution is needed **now** [slams fist on desk] :)

Comment: @gregsdennis quiet you! =]